# How to test if a variable exists

Tags: macros, spss

I need to run SPSS syntax in an IF statement, which tests if a variable exists in the document.  I am having trouble getting the IF test right.  I'm trying to do this:

```
do if (test if myVariable exists).
// execute code here
end if.
Execute.
```

I've looked [here](http://spsstools.net/en/syntax/syntax-index/test-if-file-or-variable-exists/choice-of-include-file-depends-on-existence-of-a-given-variable/) and tried this:

```
DO IF (myVariable) exist=1.
END IF.
Execute.
```

But I get the error 'There is extraneous text following the logical expression on a DO IF command.  Have I misunderstood the code?

Comment: Yes, you definitely missed the point completely ;)   In any case that code was written before `spssinc select variables` was available, which is a nice shortcut - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`spssinc select variables` command creates a list of variables according to a specified propertie. In this case the property will be the variable called "MyVar". If the variable doesn't exist, the list will stay empty:

```
spssinc select variables macroname="!findMyVar" /properties pattern="MyVar".
```

Now we define a macro that will run some commands only if the above list is not empty:

```
define doifMyVarexists ()
!if (!eval(!findMyVar)<>"") !then
  * put your commands here, like following examples.
  compute MyVar=MyVar*2.
  freq MyVar.
!ifend
!enddefine.

* the macro is ready, now we call it:
doifMyVarexists.
```

If you run this multiple times, you will face a problem that if MyVar exists once and in a later run doesn't exist - the list doesn't get emptied (it is only overwritten if there were variables to put into it).
To solve that use the following line to empty the list before running `select variables` again:

```
define !findMyVar() !enddefine.
```

Comment: thank you for your help, greatly appreciated.  Apologies for the late response.